# Pandas: Combining data items on multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a database of all customer transactions within company I work at.

| ID | Payment | Amount | Month | Year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Inward | 100 | 2 | 2005 |
| A | Outward | 200 | 2 | 2005 |
| B | Inward | 100 | 7 | 2017 |

I have hardships combining Sum/Count of Amount of those transactions per Customer ID per Month/Year.

Only item that I succeed at is combining Sum/Count of Amount of those transactions per customer ID.

```
Combined = data.groupby("ID")["Amount"].sum().rename("Sum").reset_index()
```

Can you please let me know what are the alternative solutions?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can groupby multiple columns - `df.groupby(['ID','Year','Month'])['Amount'].sum()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list of columns in `groupby` like:

```
>>> df.groupby(['ID', 'Year', 'Month', 'Payment'])['Amount'].agg(['sum', 'count'])

                       sum  count
ID Year Month Payment            
A  2005 2     Inward   100      1
              Outward  200      1
B  2017 7     Inward   100      1
```

For further:

```
>>> df.assign(Amount=np.where(df['Payment'].eq('Outward'),
                              -df['Amount'], df['Amount'])) \
      .groupby(['ID', 'Year', 'Month'])['Amount'].agg(['sum', 'count'])

               sum  count
ID Year Month            
A  2005 2     -100      2
B  2017 7      100      1
```